# How to let XMLHttpRequest not cach in IE

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
if(xmlhttp) { 
xmlhttp.open("GET","DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServletAjax?" +   $(this).prop("href").split("?")[1],true);//gettime will be the servlet name
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(null);
 }

});
});



function getXMLObject()  //XML OBJECT
{
var xmlHttp = false;
try {
 xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
  }
  catch (e) {
   try {
   xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
   }
   catch (e2) {
     xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
     }
     }
   if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera,chrome Browsers
   }
    return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
   }





  var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject(); //xmlhttp holds the ajax object


     function handleServerResponse() {

   document.getElementById("pop1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; //Update the HTML              Form element 

  }
```

Hello,
I have the following problem (the code works), the xmlhttpRequest(ajax-call) refreches when I use firefox or Chrome (so it works nice). But IE 9.0+ caches the XMLHttprequest, so it never refreches. I read alot about this problem on the internet,but i really cannot find any solution to this problem.

Can anybody tell me the possibilities to fix this?
I think it is fixable with using the jquery ajax, but I don't have the brains to tune this whole script into jquery. Some say you can set the live-time to 0 but I don't find this. (I communicate my Ajax with a servlet)
Somebody knows an clear,easier solution?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once of the accepted practice is to add a random parameter to the url like the timestamp.

Add a parameter like `_d` to the url with the value `new Date().getTime()`

Ex:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","DokterWeek_KlantoverzichtServletAjax?_d=" + (new Date().getTime()) + '&' +   $(this).prop("href").split("?")[1], true);//gettime will be the servlet name
```

Comment: Arun P Johny, Thank you again for a great answer! really works perfectly